# ng-repeat filter not working with quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I add a filter using an input type text on my ng-repeat.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputSearch" />
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:inputSearch">
    {{ item.value }}
</div>
```

if my object contain a value like **foo's bar** and I type in my input **foo's bar** it won't find anything.

I read that angular allow you to add another single quote like this **foo'' bar** to escape the quote.. but there is another way ?

I don't want to add treatment on my object.

thanks.

Comment: are you sure ? please see here http://jsbin.com/wajecu/6/edit is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem with in {{item.value}} just use  {{item}} it will work.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="inputSearch" />
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:inputSearch">
   {{ item}}
 </div>
```